# How do I get my original RAID setup running again?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, mdadm, raid5

I was trying to upgrade my raid 5 to larger drives. I was following a guide I found at:

```
https://rabexc.org/posts/mdadm-replace
```

But I could tell something was wrong before I added the larger drive. Two devices seemed to disappear. So I tried adding the original drive back. It looks like mdamd sees all 4, but I'm not sure what's wrong. All 4 of my original drives are back connected, and Ubuntu sees them. How do I get my original setup running again?

I'm running Ubuntu 20

4 drives are 4TB SATA physical disks

I think this output is likely to be the most helpful:

```
sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sd[a-z]1
/dev/sda1:
   MBR Magic : aa55
/dev/sdb1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : e73fc900:63b29dac:59abec6d:a9ed6e02
           Name : ubuntu1:0  (local to host ubuntu1)
  Creation Time : Mon Feb  1 14:28:44 2021
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 7813770895 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 11720655360 (11177.69 GiB 12001.95 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813770240 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=655 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : fc1484e3:9dd42927:050c3334:510f959c

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Mon Jul  3 22:53:17 2023
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 24 sectors
       Checksum : e373a9f0 - correct
         Events : 29259

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : A..A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : e73fc900:63b29dac:59abec6d:a9ed6e02
           Name : ubuntu1:0  (local to host ubuntu1)
  Creation Time : Mon Feb  1 14:28:44 2021
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 7813770895 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 11720655360 (11177.69 GiB 12001.95 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813770240 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=655 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : ef83a829:fb3b15d5:a8efbc06:6e1ce6ff

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Mon Jul  3 22:48:11 2023
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 24 sectors
       Checksum : d606fcd - correct
         Events : 29256

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA.A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdd1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : e73fc900:63b29dac:59abec6d:a9ed6e02
           Name : ubuntu1:0  (local to host ubuntu1)
  Creation Time : Mon Feb  1 14:28:44 2021
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 7813770895 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 11720655360 (11177.69 GiB 12001.95 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813770240 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=655 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 33674b45:e1670e28:6357bac7:54feeea5

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Mon Jul  3 22:45:08 2023
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 24 sectors
       Checksum : e301c7e1 - correct
         Events : 29253

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sde1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : e73fc900:63b29dac:59abec6d:a9ed6e02
           Name : ubuntu1:0  (local to host ubuntu1)
  Creation Time : Mon Feb  1 14:28:44 2021
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 7813770895 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 11720655360 (11177.69 GiB 12001.95 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813770240 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=655 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : effdc94e:e1c09065:676782d9:11099abc

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Mon Jul  3 22:53:17 2023
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 24 sectors
       Checksum : 5274d44e - correct
         Events : 29259

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : A..A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

Update:

It looks like my drives are out of sync?

```
/dev/sdb1:
         Events : 29259
   Device Role : Active device 0
/dev/sdc1:
         Events : 29256
   Device Role : Active device 1
/dev/sdd1:
         Events : 29253
   Device Role : Active device 2
/dev/sde1:
         Events : 29259
   Device Role : Active device 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this command below fixed the syncing issue. I mostly understand it, but also don't know what I don't know about this.

One learning was that I didn't have to have the /dev/sdx1 drives in any specific order. As a software RAID on Linux, it reads the identifying information from the drives, and uses that info to assemble it. I'm just passing which devices to consider.

mdadm --assemble --run --force --update=resync /dev/md127 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1